# How do I send and receive vectors in my tcp server/client setup?

Tags: rust, tcp

I ahve a really simple tcp client/server setup that I found somewhere online.

```
use std::net::{Shutdown,TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;
use std::io::{Read,Write,Error};

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream)-> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("incoming connection from: {}", stream.peer_addr()?);
    let mut buf = [0;512];
    loop {
        let bytes_read = stream.read(&mut buf)?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {return Ok(())}
        let tmp = format!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf).trim());
        eprintln!("getting {}",tmp);
        stream.write(&vec![1,2,3,4])?;
    }
}

fn main() {
    
    
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8888").expect("Could not bind");
    let mut i = 0;
    for stream in listener.incoming() {

        match stream {
            Err(e)=> {eprintln!("failed: {}", e)}
            Ok(stream) => {
                
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream).unwrap_or_else(|error| eprintln!("{:?}", error));
                });
                
                
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

and the client looks like so:

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::str;
use std::io::{self,BufRead,BufReader,Write};


fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("0.0.0.0:8888").expect("could not  connect");
    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        let mut buffer : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("failed to read stdin");
        stream.write(input.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write to server");

        let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);

        reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).expect("Could not read into buffer");

        println!("{}", str::from_utf8(&buffer).expect("msg: &str"))
    }
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

(actually vs code tells me that the code inside the loop here is unreachable, which is false)

But this basically just lets the client send a message to the server, that the server sends back.

I would actually like to send vectors back and forth, which actually seems like a simpler task.

So, I change the line in the server that writes to the stream to this:

```
stream.write(&vec![1,2,3,4])?;
```

and now, in the client that prints the message it gets from the serve to:

```
println!("{:?}", &buffer)
```

But when I do this, nothing happens on the clientside, nothing is printed, and it seems like the loop is just stuck somewhere.

I gugess it has something to do with this line:

```
reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).expect("Could not read into buffer");
```

and I read some other way of reading in. I tried using a function from tcpstream called "read_vectored", but I can't use it at all for the stream object I have.

Comment: Your `stream.write()` call is just sending the 4 byte values 1,2,3,4 without any kind of length or type information. How is the receiver to know when it has finished reading the vector or what kind of content it contains? You need some kind of framing to indicate this information to the receiver.

Comment: yes, how does one do that?

Comment: There's no one single way. You could serialize the vector as a JSON array, or an XML document, or CSV, or using something like protocol buffers, or...

Comment: hmm, I haven't really been able to find any examples or info on how I would do that. I'm assuming some serialization would be ok